# Implement a reset button to take back removed DOM elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

How to implement a **reset** button to take back removed DOM elements in jQuery?

php array `$items = array('a','b','c','d')`

**Markup**

```
<table id="table">
    <?php for( $i=0; $i < count( $items ); $i++ ){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i + 1;?></td> // No
        <td><?php echo $items[$i];?></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='DEL' value='DELETE'></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
<input type="reset" id="RESET" value="Reset">
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click','#RESET', function() {
    // Code call back from db then show to display
    // example select * from school 
});
```

But I am not sure if that is right, because it will get to

```
a,b,c,a,b,c,d,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=0; $i<(count($items)); $i++){
?><tr>
    <td><?php echo ($i+1);?></td> // No
    <td>
        <?php echo $items[$i]; ?> // a,b,c,d
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='button' class='DEL' value='DELETE'> // delete row
    </td>
</tr><?php
}
<input type="reset" id="RESET" value="Reset">
```

In footer section of your document, have this snippet within `<script>` tags:

```
window.a = new Array('a','b','c','d');

$('#RESET').click(function(){
  $('#table').empty();
  $.each(a, function(index, element) {
    $('#table').append('<tr><td>'+(index+1)+'<td>'+element+'</td><td><input type="button" class="DEL" value="DELETE"></td></tr>');
  });
});
```

## UPDATE

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6e3aeq1/4/)